# Python file as class

Tags: python

I have a package `myapp` with the following structure:

```
/myapp
  __init__.py
  User.py
```

Inside the User.py:

```
from flask_login import UserMixin
class User(UserMixin):

    def __init__(self, id):
      #more
```

To import it I have to use:

```
from myapp.User import User
```

Is it possible to self-define the `user.py` file as a class the same way you can in Java? And then import it: `from myapp import User`?

I guess that the only way to do is define the User inside the `__init__.py`. Is it so?

Comment: You can import `User` in `__init__.py`: `from User import User` and then `from myapp import User` should work fine. But what's wrong with the current way?

Comment: If `user.py` only defines a single class, then perhaps it can be merged with another module.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary *don't use implicit relative imports*. Either use an explicit relative import `from .user import User` (note the dot in `.user`) or use an absolute import `from myapp.user import User`. Using implicit relative import *will* break code when moving to different python versions *and* can even break code in other ways (e.g. problems with pickled data using the `User` class imported in the wrong way).

Comment: @Bakuriu Thanks for the info, my bad I missed a `.`.

Answer (score 1):

You can import your class inside `__init__.py` to make it directly available for importing through the package:

```
from .User import User
```

Be wary though that this masks the User module in this case where the module name equals the class name. This hinders users of your package from importing the module itself using a simple `import` statement.

They can still get to it through `sys.modules` (or `importlib.import_module()` for that matter) and import objects defined within the module using `from … import …` (e.g. `from app.User import user_related_function` will still work and import `user_related_function` from `app.User` [the module] despite `app.User` referring to `app.User.User` in your local namespace).

Comment: I'm not sure if it does mask the submodule making it un-importable...  `import package.module` should still work I think ...

Comment: @mgilson It will definitely mask the module, but we can still use `sys.modules['myapp.User']` to get the module itself. Something similar was asked earlier(I couldn't find it though)which pointed out the issue in https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/simplify/__init__.py file, here the module `fu` can now only be imported using `sys.modules`.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `import myapp`, you're really importing `myapp/__init__.py`'s namespace into the local namespace under the name `myapp`.  When you say:  `from myapp import something`, you're taking `something` in the global namespace of `myapp` and bringing it into the local namespace.

SO, to have it the way you want, you just need to do this in `__init__.py`

```
# __init__.py
from myapp.User import User
# alternatively, using package local imports:
# from .User import User
```

Because now `__init__.py` holds a reference to the User class in it's global namespace and from there, that reference can be imported elsewhere.